# Image not showing up in SDL

Tags: c++, image, sdl

When I run this it just shows a black screen, and if i Put SDL_GetError() at the end it prints a blank line.....

Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include <iostream>

class character {

public: SDL_Rect src, cur;
public: SDL_Texture *image;

void setSrc(int x, int y, int w, int h) {

    src.x = x;
    src.y = y;
    src.w = w;
    src.h = h;

}

void setCur(int x, int y, int w, int h) {

    src.x = x;
    src.y = y;
    src.w = w;
    src.h = h;

}

};  

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

bool in = true;
character p1, p2, ball; 
SDL_Window *window = 0;
SDL_Renderer *renderer = 0;
SDL_Surface *screen, *imageLoader;

SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

window = SDL_CreateWindow("Pong",SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);

p1.setSrc(0, 0, 100, 500);
p1.setCur(0, 0, 100, 500);

imageLoader = IMG_Load("/home/donaldo/Documents/Games/Images/player.bmp");

p1.image = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, imageLoader);

SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, p1.image, &p1.src, &p1.cur);

SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

SDL_Delay(3000);

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your `setCur()` function. I assume you want to be setting the `cur` rectangle, not `src` again.

Also, not related but it's good practice to free the surface and texture you allocated when you're done with them.